# 2Checkout Sandbox Payment

Tags: 2checkout

This is the first time I am using the sandbox account.

The following code I am using.

```
HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
 params.put("sid", "cccc");
 params.put("mode", "2CO");
 params.put("li_0_type", "product");
 params.put("li_0_name", "Test");
 params.put("li_0_price", "1.00");




 String form = TwocheckoutCharge.submit(params);

 form = "<html>" + form + "</html>";

 return form;
```

It successfully take me to the purchase page . But I am not getting the payment options and correct page .

I am facing `ERROR CODE:PE102` Error .

Following is the screent shot of the page.

What is the problem , Why I am not getting my Product Test.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All sellers as well as buyers may receive the message `ERROR CODE PE102` for several reasons:

- All Parameter Sets:
- Account is not approved to sell.
- Account has been closed.
- Nonexistent seller, or an invalid value for “sid” or “x_login” was passed in.
- Sandbox sale is being passed to live production checkout URL. All Sandbox sales must be passed to https://sandbox.2checkout.com/checkout/purchase

Reference: http://help.2checkout.com/articles/Knowledge_Article/Error-Code-PE102

Comment: How can I redirect to sandbox payment page.
since the TwocheckoutCharge.submit(params) gives me live url: `"https://www.2checkout.com/checkout/spurchase`

Comment: This will help you http://help.2checkout.com/articles/Knowledge_Article/Plug-and-Play-Buy-Button-parameter-set/?q=change+https%3A%2F%2Fsandbox.2checkout.com%2Fcheckout%2Fpurchase&l=en_US&fs=Search&pn=1

Comment: any idea on what the difference between the sandbox url and the demo flag is? I've been using the demo flag successfully for many years and just in the last few months it has broken. 2checkout support is pretty diabolical, as is their documentation, so any help would be awesome....

Answer (score 0):

Considering all the above points

The reference link is not working now in 2020:

Here is you can create Sandbox Account: http://sandbox.2checkout.com